Audio not playing in Asp.net MVC
I'm having issue on playing audio in asp.net. I have
@if (ViewBag.First != null && ViewBag.First)
{
  <audio id="welcome" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="~/asset/audio/site-music/site-music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
}

What is happening now is,



Scenario
Condition
Expected result
Actual Result




When I start project(clear all cookies)
I'm new visitor
Should Play
Fail


clear all cookies on the same page and reload
I'm new visitor
Should Play
Fail


clear all cookies navigate to different page and back to this page.
I'm new visitor
Should Play
Pass


Cookie are stored, navigated to different page already and back to this page.
I'm not a new visitor
Shouldn't Play
Pass



I'm having doubts that whether it will play when I deploy the with changes or not. Here, I have just added one condition, if its first visit then only play audio. Otherwise don't play audio again and again. When condition doesn't match. It doesn't even load the audio element. But when it is loaded it should play which is not working.
Edit :
Without condition as well it is working in the same way in local environment. It seems like Asp.Net issue while reloading/navigating though URL.
